# Actualizacion de paginas web y frameworks online

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

Tengo una inquietud cuál es la mejor forma de ofrecer actualizaciones a desarrollos que se entregan a clientes.

Soy programadora y desarrolladora full stack, ya tengo varios años de experiencia en el desarrollo, pero casualmente nunca me he encontrado con esta situación.

La idea es saber cuál es la mejor forma de aplicar actualizaciones de software que se entregue a los clientes, siempre he hecho las actualizaciones de forma manual, entro al administrador del servidor para cambiar archivos, o lo hago a través de una cuenta FTP y manualmente hago las modificaciones a la base de datos que se requieran.

Principalmente desarrollo en PHP y JS, quisiera saber cuál es el mejor método para poder cambiar archivos PHP, JS, HTML, CSS, además de poder cambiar tablas en base de datos SQL principalmente con MySQL. La idea es poder ofrecerle a los clientes actualizaciones sin tener que tener acceso al cpanel o al servidor como tal, he desarrollado un framwork propio similar a laravel y estoy lanzando varias tiendas online de desarrollo propio.

¿Cuál es el mejor método para aplicar actualizaciones? ¿Hay una librería para esto?. La idea es que el software se pueda comunicar a mi servidor y así poder detectar si hay una actualización disponible y así poder que esta se aplique automáticamente sin tener que entrar directamente al servidor y hacer los cambios manualmente.

Se que puede ser un concepto muy básico, pero me gustaría saber cuáles métodos recomiendan o como lo hacen ustedes y así aprender a hacer este proceso y poder aplicarlo en las páginas web o aplicativos online que uno le entregue a los clientes.

Pensaba diseñar y desarrollar un script en PHP que se encargue de detectar la actualización y realice el reemplazo de los archivos e hiciera los cambios a la base de datos por código SQL, pero no sé si es el mejor camino.

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo estás llevando el control de actualizaciones (o versiones) en tu proyecto? Lo necesitas para saber si ya se realizó determinada actualización. Teniendo esa parte solucionada ya no es tan complicado, solo necesitas llevar control de las modificaciones y crear un paquete de actualización, de preferencia en un archivo comprimido. El software debe hacer una petición a tu servidor para ver las actualizaciones disponibles y dar la opción al usuario para descargar e instalar.

Comment: Me temo que la pregunta terminará cerrada por estar basada en opiniones y esas preguntas están fuera del tema, como se explica en el [help/dont-ask]. Lo que puedo recomendarte es observar como funcionan las actualizaciones de CMS's como joomla, wordpress, drupal (y muchos más). Hacer un sistema de actualización puede requerir un esfuerzo que va de mediano a considerable, dependiendo de su robustez y la complejidad de tu sistema. Básicamente es empacar scripts de bases de datos, archivos y otros artefactos necesarios, y tener un programa que sepa aplicarlos y copiarlos.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer se llama de manera general, integración continua, entrega contínua y/o despliegue continuo (CI/CD), Hay varios softwares que hacen esto, yo uso gitlab. La forma en que funciona en mi caso es: todos los push deployan en un server, los merges deployan en otro server.  El deploy hace lo que harías manualmente, borra todo del server y lo pasa usando scp. Todo este proceso es mucho mas fácil usando docker, por ejemplo si la actualización implica la instalación de paquetes en el servidor, usando docker también resolvería eso, de manera que en servidor no hay que hacer nada.

Comment: El control de versiones lo hago con GIt y sourcetree, pero solamente en la parte de desarrollo y para el servidor privado de desarrollo. Me aclara muchas dudas el concepto de CI/CD, muchas gracias no lo conocía como tal, ese último comentario me ha ayudado bastante para aclarar conceptos.

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado, para hacer las "modificaciones en la base de datos", si existe un método estandarizado, que es el uso de migraciones, o sea, que a cada versión se adjuntan archivos con las consultas necesarias para modificar las bases de datos, al terminar la actualización, todas las migraciones que aún no corrieron deben correr. Creo que el mejor ejemplo de uso de este sistema es Ruby on Rails.

Por otro lado está la cuestión de la actualización del código y en este punto es muy importante resaltar la importancia del uso de firmas criptográficas y la verificación de las mismas, ya que muchos ataques se enfocan en las vulnerabilidades en el proceso de actualización para instalar código malicioso.

Dicho eso, para manejar las actualizaciones lo mejor a mi criterio es utilizar un gestor de paquetes, utilizar la aplicación como un paquete (privado), e integrar a la misma el gestor de paquetes para actualizar la misma aplicación. No soy experto en PHP, pero por lo que veo https://packagist.com/ parece permitir eso.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías integrar a tu flujo de trabajo, el despliegue continuo, en el cual al subir ciertos cambios en una rama especifica empleando una herramienta de control de versiones git (GitHub, GitLab... etc), te automatice todo el proceso sin necesidad de que lo realices tu manualmente.

Por lo que entiendo, trabajas con php y suponiendo que empleas GitHub, como herramienta para el control de versiones, te comparto algunos enlaces con tutoriales que te permitirán automatizar tu despliegue a producción:

- https://jnjsite.com/scripts-y-tecnicas-de-despliegue-continuo-para-una-web-con-git/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXRUMzlibTg
- https://soporte.dongee.com/es/articles/3299207-desplegar-laravel-en-cpanel

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).